# Validate url parameters in php

Tags: php, validation, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have rules in my .htaccess for pages, show property id etc...

I want to make sure I validate every parameter I get to the right query im getting.

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ property.php?pid=$1
```

so in my php I do:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

and

```
$propertyid = $_GET['pid'];
```

Now I need to secure them but I want to know which method is best to use to secure these and that is where im lost.

Comment: $_GET['page'] = numeric and letters only? $_GET['pid'] is numeric only?

Comment: this question is all over the place. 1) what does this have to do with SEO? 2) what do you mean by "validate" and/or "secure"?

Comment: yes i only get numeric and letters for page and numeric for pid

Comment: well i dont want my url to be property.php?pid=2 or page.php?page=contact

Comment: what kind of security you are trying to secure? SQL injection? then just escape the string or use sprintf with appropriate type passing will do the job

Comment: The first rule includes the second one. Doubtfully they work

Comment: @YouQi: How the hell does `sprintf` help against SQL injection if you have a string argument?

Comment: `well i dont want my url to be property.php?pid=2 or page.php?page=contact` --- what does that mean? You already have that urls worked

Comment: @ThiefMaster as I said, you either escape the string (tons of function to do the same job, like mysql_real_escape_string) OR use sprintf for fields require numeric entry

Comment: So why not just use `intval()` for numeric values..?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would say to use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^property/([0-9]+)/?$ property.php?pid=$1 [L,NC]
```

this way if someone enters any characters other than letters and numbers (for pages) and numbers (for property) it will show a page not found.

If you want *really* to be sure, you can

`$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);` just make sure your database connection is open and you can cast the pid like `$propertyid = (int)$_GET['pid'];`

Answer (score 0):

i think with page parameter you should have a list of acept pages, then after get 'page', you check if 'page' is in accept list.
For example :

```
$arr_pages = ('page1','page2','page3');
$page = $_GET['page'];
if(in_array($page,$arr_pages))
{
// do some thing
}
else
{
 // page not found
}
```

And id :

```
$propertyid = intval($_GET['pid']);
```

hope this help :)